# How do i save PHP form input in MySQL database using same script as form input and validation

Tags: php, mysql

I have a registration-form page that doubles as the validation script. Everything seems to work fine up to the point where the form input is validated. 
But when the form input is supposed to be saved in the database, PHP reloads 
the script as if there's still an error with one of the inputs. 
Once, I placed

```
if(count($errors) < 1)
```

outside of

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
```

for a change. It naturally saved the form default input in the database. Which isn't safe. So I placed the snippet back in it's original place.
I believe it should work based on the examples I saw in google results. Mine just keeps running in a loop.

I've posted the script on [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/aowasiu/e4f7462af25b6935d4ab) so maybe someone spots something I might have missed.

Comment: The php is hard to read without proper tab indentation. :-)

Comment: Please include a [mcve] directly in your question. Emphasis on minimal.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if you are using a single equals sign ( = ) when **comparing** data, when a single equals is supposed to be used as an **assignment operator**. Please use a double equals sign ( == ) when comparing data.